# Wordpress Custom font not found

Tags: theme-development, themes

I created a custom wordpress theme from scratch 
I am trying to use custom font
what I done
upload font to `wp-content/themes/mythemefolder/fonts/fontfolder`
 in theme default style.css

```
@font-face {
        font-family: "fontname";
        src: url('fonts/fontfolder/fontname.otf');
}
*{font-family: "fontname";}
```

when I visti page text are not in desired font
I check console show error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://domainname.com/wp-content/themes/mythemefolder/fonts/fontfolder/fontname.otf
```

path of font in console is correct but still font not working

what mistake I am making

thanks in advance for help

Comment: Could you please share me your site URL where it's happening so that i can troubleshoot it?

Comment: @VinodDalvi - http://digiw3lab.com/wp/

Comment: It seems either the font doesn't exist on the path http://digiw3lab.com/wp/wp-content/themes/1965/fonts/gotham/gotham-book.otf or doesn't have read permission so please check and resolve it.

Comment: path exist in console if u click the path, font will open in application tab & permission is 755 to folder & 644 to files

Comment: You are not getting my point. The font should download on clicking on its above shared link but this is not happening. Please share the screenshot of how you have saved the font.